# wagmi useContractRead is giving error and data together

Tags: javascript, wagmi

I am trying to simply read smart contract data by calling an `external view` function `getOwner` which returns an ethereum address using wagmi hook `useContractRead`. I found that I am getting both the `error` and `data` fields non-empty. On further inspection I found that the data that I am getting is correct but the`error` is also not empty and the `isError` is also set to `true`.

This is the error message string that I am getting

```bash
"Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transaction={\"gasLimit\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x01bad458\"},\"to\":\"0xb16DeC9F103B1bf9393380A05363995177C6954C\",\"data\":\"0x893d20e8\",\"accessList\":null}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)\n    at Logger.makeError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:231:23)\n    at Logger.throwError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js:240:20)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib.esm/fallback-provider.js:573:28)\n    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)\n    at FallbackProvider.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib.esm/fallback-provider.js:553:37)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib.esm/fallback-provider.js:19:58)"
```

This is the sample code I am using to read data

```js
import ...  // imported necessary packages and modules
...

export default function OwnerDashboard() {
    const router = useRouter()

    const { address: account, isConnected } = useAccount()

    const { chain } = useNetwork()
    const chainId = chain?.id.toString() || "31337"
    console.log(chainId, account)

    const contractReader = useContractRead({
        abi: PatientMedicalRecordSystemAbi,
        address: networkMapping[chainId].PatientMedicalRecordSystem[0],
        functionName: "getOwner",
        onError(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
    console.log(contractReader?.data)
}
```

The contract function which I am invoking is `getOwner` from [this](https://github.com/sadityakumar9211/medichain-hardhat/blob/fbd8573a31ae40b8cf98f57c13126edcea7c9234/contracts/PatientMedicalRecordSystem.sol#L278) contract.

Am I using `wagmi` the wrong way to get the data out? Or what is the issue?